# checkout/session setQuote

Tags: checkout, adminhtml, session

I am working with a module that has a lot of hard-coded calls to 
`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()`
I am trying to call it from Adminhtml and in stead of rewriting a huge chunk of the module, I thought I would set the checkout session quote to the quote stored in my object (which is valid). However when I type the code:

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
    ->setQuote($this->getQuote())
    ->save();`

I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed'`

Is there a quick way to override the checkout/session's quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you want to load a quote from the admin you would use

```
/**
 * Retrieve quote object
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
 */
protected function _getQuote()
{
    return $this->_getSession()->getQuote();
}

/**
 * Retrieve session object
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote
 */
protected function _getSession()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
}
```

So if you know the quote id then you could try loading the quote

```
$this->_getSession()->clear();
$this->_getQuote()->setQuoteId($id)->setStoreId($store_id)->setIsActive(true)->load($id);
```

Comment: Although this wasn't exactly what I was trying to do since I wanted to avoid editing the 3rd party module, I ended up going with this. Thanks R.S.